# Is there a specific formula for the product of the first k prime numbers, each raised to a certain power minus 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\prod_{i=1}^k(p_i^{e_i}-1)$$

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PX3u.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: What’s your thoughts?

Comment: Please type up your question instead of relying on a link.

Comment: If $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_n$, then the formula counts the positive integers up to a given integer n that are relatively prime to $n$.  see [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the expression is what you're looking for, but her we go:

Given a positive integer $n$, define:

- $\text{rad}(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}p$, where $p$ is a prime
- $\sigma_1(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} d$, where $d$ is any positive divisor of $n$
- $\phi(n)=n\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)$, [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Let $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{e_k}$ then $$\prod_{i=1}^k(p_i^{e_i}-1)=\prod_{i=1}^k(p_i-1)\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{p_i^{e_i}-1}{p_i-1}=\phi(\text{rad}(n))\sigma_1\left (\frac{n}{\text{rad}(n)}\right)$$

Comment: thank you so much